# Sobolev space of disjoint union of open sets

Tags: functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations

Let $\Omega_{1}$, $\Omega_{2}$ be two disjoint bounded open sets in $\mathbb{R}^{N}$, i.e. $\Omega_{1}\cap \Omega_{2} = \emptyset$

Is it true that one can express $H_{0}^{1}(\Omega_{1} \cup \Omega_{2})$ in the form $\displaystyle H_{0}^{1}(\Omega_{1} \cup \Omega_{2})\equiv \lbrace u+v \mid u \in H_{0}^{1}(\Omega_{1}),v\in H_{0}^{1}(\Omega_{2})\rbrace$?

I have kind of convinced myself that the R.H.S. is a subspace of the L.H.S but I'm not sure about the other way, or even if it should be true.

Answer (score 0):

This looks correct to me. Let me give you a hint: By density it is enough to show
$$C^\infty_0(\Omega_1\cup\Omega_2)=\{u+v|\ u\in C^\infty_0(\Omega_1), v\in C^\infty_0(\Omega_2)\}.$$
Now take an $f\in C^\infty_0(\Omega_1\cup\Omega_2)$ and try to show that the support of $f$ can be splitted up into two parts, which lie in $\Omega_1$ and $\Omega_2$ respectively. What kind of regularity does $f\cdot \chi_{\Omega_1}$ now possess and where is the support of it? Here $\chi_A(x)=1$ if $x\in A$ and $0$ otherwise.

Comment: Thanks for this! I can see where to go from here. I'd driven myself crazy by thinking about it in a silly way but this is much better.

Answer (score 0):

Let me leave at least some notes of a proof for anyone who looks here. Let $\Omega_{1}$, $\Omega_{2}$ be disjoint  bounded open sets and $\Omega = \Omega_{1}\cup \Omega_{2}$.

**Lemma 1.** Suppose that $K\Subset \Omega$, then $K_{1}=K\cap \Omega_{1} \Subset \Omega_{1}$ and $K_{2}=K\cap \Omega_{2} \Subset \Omega_{2}$. ($\Subset$ means compactly contained here)

*Proof.* It suffices to show that $K_{1} \subset \Omega_{1}$ is closed. Let $x_{n}$ be a sequence in $K_{1}$ then by compactness it has a subsequence we denote $x_{n}$ also that converges to some $x\in K$. $x$ cannot be in $K_{2}$ since as each of $K_{1}$ and $K_{2}$ is at least some positive distance from the boundaries $\partial \Omega_{1}$ and $\partial \Omega_{2}$ respectively. Thus, $x\in K_{1}$ and hence $K_{1}$ is closed. $\square$

**Lemma 2.** We have that $C_{c}^{\infty}(\Omega) = C_{c}^{\infty}(\Omega_{1}) \oplus C_{c}^{\infty}(\Omega_{2})$

*Proof.* The inclusions $C_{c}^{\infty}(\Omega_{1}),C_{c}^{\infty}(\Omega_{2}) \subset C_{c}^{\infty}(\Omega)$ are clear and thus, noting that $C_{c}^{\infty}(\Omega_{1})\cap C_{c}^{\infty}(\Omega_{2}) = \lbrace 0\rbrace$, $C_{c}^{\infty}(\Omega_{1})\oplus C_{c}^{\infty}(\Omega_{2}) \subset C_{c}^{\infty}(\Omega)$.
Now we show that every $f\in C_{c}^{\infty}(\Omega)$ can be decomposed into $f=f_{1} +f_{2}$ where $f_{1}\in C_{c}^{\infty}(\Omega_{1})$ and $f_{2}\in C_{c}^{\infty}(\Omega_{2})$. Well let $S_{1} = \operatorname{supp}(f)\cap \Omega_{1}$ and $S_{2} = \operatorname{supp}(f)\cap \Omega_{2}$. Then notice that $S_{1}\cup S_{2} = \operatorname{supp}(f)$ and $S_{1},S_{2}$ are compactly contained in $\Omega_{1},\Omega_{2}$ respectively. Define $f_{1} = \left.f\right|_{\Omega_{1}}$ and $f_{2} = \left.f\right|_{\Omega_{2}}$. Then we have that $\operatorname{supp}(f_{1})=S_{1},\operatorname{supp}(f_{2})=S_{2}$. Notice that $f = f_{1}+f_{2}$ and thus we have the result. $\square$

**Result 1.** We have that $H_{0}^{1}(\Omega) = H_{0}^{1}(\Omega_{1})\oplus H_{0}^{1}(\Omega_{2})$.

*Proof.* $H_{0}^{1}(\Omega_{1})\oplus H_{0}^{1}(\Omega_{2}) \subset H_{0}^{1}(\Omega)$ similarly as to previous lemma. For $u\in H_{0}^{1}(\Omega)$  we can find some sequence $\phi_{n} = \phi_{n}^{(1)}+\phi_{n}^{(2)} \in C_{c}^{\infty}(\Omega)$ which converges to $u$ in the $H^{1}$ norm. Now we have that

$\displaystyle \begin{split} \lVert \phi_{n} - u \rVert_{H_{0}^{1}(\Omega)}^{2} & = \sum_{|\alpha| \leq 1}\int_{\Omega}(\phi_{n} - u)^{2} \\ & = \sum_{|\alpha| \leq 1}\int_{\Omega_{1}}(\left.\phi_{n}\right|_{\Omega_{1}} - u)^{2}+\sum_{|\alpha| \leq 1}\int_{\Omega_{2}}(\left.\phi_{n}\right|_{\Omega_{2}} - u)^{2} \\ &= \lVert \left.\phi_{n}\right|_{\Omega_{1}} - u \rVert_{H_{0}^{1}(\Omega_{1})}^{2}+\lVert \left.\phi_{n}\right|_{\Omega_{2}} - u \rVert_{H_{0}^{1}(\Omega_{2})}^{2} \end{split}$

Now observe that $\lVert \phi_{n} - u \rVert_{H_{0}^{1}(\Omega)}^{2} \to 0 \Leftrightarrow \lVert \left.\phi_{n}\right|_{\Omega_{1}} - u \rVert_{H_{0}^{1}(\Omega_{1})}^{2},\lVert \left.\phi_{n}\right|_{\Omega_{2}} - u \rVert_{H_{0}^{1}(\Omega_{2})}^{2} \to 0$ as $n\to\infty$. Thus, we have the desired result. $\square$

As an important remark we needn't make any assumptions on the whether $\overline{\Omega_{1}\cup \Omega_{2}}$ is connected.

---

As a point of curiosity notice that if $\lambda$ is a Dirichlet eigenvalue of $\Omega_{1}$ with normalised eigenfunction $u_{n}$ we have that for all $v\in H_{0}^{1}(\Omega)$

$\displaystyle  \lambda\int_{\Omega}u_{n}v =  \lambda\int_{\Omega_{1}}u_{n}\left.v\right|_{\Omega_{1}} = \int_{\Omega_{1}}\nabla u_{n} \cdot \nabla \left.v\right|_{\Omega_{1}} = \int_{\Omega}\nabla u_{n} \cdot \nabla v$.

So $\lambda$ is also a Dirichlet eigenvalue of $\Omega$ with eigenfunction $u_{n}$.

Best,
Cryptokyo

(SF)